# How to convert a contour list into a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

In this code I want to save all the contours in one `.h5` file. But this is possible only when I convert the contours to a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import cv2

thresh,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = False)[40:50]
l = len(contours)
cnts = []

for i,contour in enumerate(contours):
    contour = np.array(contour,dtype = np.int32)
    cnts.append(contour)

cnts = np.array(cnts).astype('int32')
directory = 'Hist_defects'
os.makedirs(directory,exist_ok = True)
h = h5py.File('Hist_defects/'+str(k)+'.h5') 
h.create_dataset('dataset_1',data=cnts)
h.close()
```

I get the following error when I run this.

```
cnts = np.array(cnts).astype('int32')
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Is this kind of conversion possible?

Comment: Since `contour` is an array and not an `int32`, try replacing `cnts = np.array(cnts).astype('int32')` by `cnts = np.array(cnts).astype('object')`

Comment: I think the code is incorrect, I never heard of `np.acnts`. It would be easier if you actually **show** your `contours` in the question. That way one can easily reproduce the code.

Comment: @MSeifert it was a typo. I have now corrected it

Comment: @AtulBalaji What about the contours? They should be only 10 elements long. Could you include that list in the question?

Comment: @Nuageux Now I am getting another error:

Comment: Just use `print(repr(contours))` after the `sorted` line and include that output.

Comment: [ ]                                                                                                                          
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hotspot_hist.py", line 66, in <module>
    h.create_dataset('dataset_1',data=cnts)                                                          This is the output. @MSeifert

Comment: Just show what `contours` are. Just temporarly comment everything after that.

Comment: Can you `print contours` or `contours.shape` and provide full output (edit your question to make it easier to read than in a comment)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens when the elements in your `contours` don't have equal lengths:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> contours = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]  # not equal lengths
>>> cnts = []

>>> for contour in contours:
...     cnts.append(np.array(contour, dtype=np.int32))

>>> cnts = np.array(cnts).astype('int32')
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

That's because NumPy doesn't support ["ragged arrays"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array). You could pad the shorter ones with some other value and then save them.

```
>>> contours = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]

>>> maxlength = max(map(len, contours))

>>> cnts = []
>>> for contour in contours:
...     contour_arr = np.zeros(maxlength, dtype=np.int32)
...     contour_arr[:len(contour)] = contour
...     cnts.append(contour_arr)

>>> np.array(cnts)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 0]])
```

Instead of `np.zeros` you could also use [`np.full`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) to choose another "missing value".

It's a bit more complicated if the `contours` are multidimensional. But in that case you can also use [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html).

Comment: I am getting the following error:                                                                                                          `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hotspot_hist.py", line 55, in <module>
    maxlength = max(map(len, contours))
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`

Comment: Please show your `contours`, the answer contains all the information necessary for **you to fix the problem.** If you need more help you **have to** share your data. Otherwise it's just not possible to give you more help.

Comment: When I gave `print(contours)`, it printed out a long list of points like this and gave the following error:                                                                             [[616, 589]],

       [[615, 588]],

       [[609, 588]],

       [[608, 587]],

       [[605, 587]],

       [[604, 586]]], dtype=int32)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hotspot_hist.py", line 61, in <module>
    contour_arr[:len(contour)] = contour
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (21,1,2) into shape (21)

Comment: @AtulBalaji Could you check if the solution works if you use `np.zeros((maxlength, 1, 2), dtype=np.int32)`? instead of the `np.zeros` call I have in the answer.

Comment: Since I have made some of the contours zero, when I draw the contours, the top left corner is always being included. How do I exclude this point?       @MSeifert

Comment: @AtulBalaji Depends on how you load them and you how you want to use them. I think asking a **new question** would make sense. Feel free to provide a link in the comments here, I'll take a look at it :)